# What should I do when threatened by a moderator?

Tags: support, moderators, abuse

What should I do when threatened by a moderator? Where should it be reported?

Comment: An actual diamond moderator or just a community member that's perhaps closed your question? What do you mean by "threatened"? Also, your third question has nothing to do with your first two.

Comment: a diamond mod, and I needed enough text before the filter would accept. I actually  had the full question in the title. feel free to remove the third one if you can.

Comment: This is almost certainly a simple misunderstanding. Moderators are highly trusted members of the site, and if you feel "threatened" (by any user) it can surely be resolved via a civil discussion on meta or chat.

Comment: @Doorknob I would like to think you are right, but I think you are wrong.

Comment: @Doorknob is correct, moderators are reasonable people and as mentioned, trusted and under more scrutiny that ordinary members.  A civil and robust discussion can resolve any issues and misconceptions.

Comment: @hildred: It would nice to have some context. Can you share it?

Comment: It doesn't really seem necessary @PatrickHofman. Nothing the community can or should do about this. Just mail the team and they will handle it.

Comment: @Bart: Agreed. But my guess is OP just misunderstood a mod. We could clarify for him.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the "contact us" link at the foot of every page on every site.